# 404 not found when I add a new middleware to handle the path in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to do the user authentication and return a page after the user clicks the login button, I start the project by using express-generator and write the following code in index.js and login.js:

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

login.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET main page after user have logged in. */
router.get("/login",function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home');
});
module.exports = router;
```

p.s index and home are the pug file in views folder

It is my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

When I type npm start, the index.js works and show the page correctly, but when I type localhost:3000/login, it shows 404 not found, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
app.use('/login', login)
```

Combined with this:

```
router.get("/login", ...)
```

Creates a route handler for the path `/login/login`.

Because you are mounting the `login` router on `/login`, the router itself should define its paths relative to that mountpoint, like this:

```
router.get("/", ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint is actually at `/login/login`. The route files append to the urls set in the app.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// `/` Is appended to `/login`
router.get("/",function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score -1):

make the below changes in login.js:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home');
});
```